# Cannot compile libgit2 with SSH support

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, libgit2, libssh2

I am trying to build gnome-builder but it says recompile libgit2 with ssh support..I have installed libssh2-1[image]-dev but doesnt help

Comment: That screen shows you trying to compile gnome builder. You need to build your copy of libgit2 after installing the development package for libgit2. If it still doesn't find it, then that'd likely be a bug.

Comment: Yeah i hv built libgit2 but still it shows the same